# Google Drive API V3: 404 file not found error on download or export the shared PDF

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm using Google Drive API V3 with PHP and trying to [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get) or [export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export) the file which is shared with me by other person. But getting **404 File Not Found** error.

```
Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 404, "message": "File not found: ******************FILE ID****************.", 
    "errors": [ { "message": "File not found: ******************FILE ID****************.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "location": "fileId", "locationType": "parameter" } ] } } in /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:134 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(107): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google\\Service\\...') #1 [internal function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google\\Service\\...') #2 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Task/Runner.php(187): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(66): Google\Task\Runner->run() #4 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(922): Google\Http\REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google\\Service\\...', Array, NULL) #5 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Service/Resource.php(238): Google\Client->execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google\\Service\\...') #6 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Drive/Resource/Files.php(208): Google\Service\Resource->call('get', Array, 'Google\\Service\\...') #7 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/lib/class.Google.php(142): Google\Service\Drive\Resource\Files->get('1lkzQpHZpCBvuG8...') #8 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/direct_services/downloadRHdrivefile.php(25): GoogleClass->downloadFile('1lkzQpHZpCBvuG8...', 'patient/80/') #9 /var/www/html/promptly_develop/hl7/direct_services/downloadRHdrivefile.php(36): DownloadDriveFile->getFile() #10 {main}
```

Using scope `$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');`

Download file code snippet given below:

```
    public function downloadFile($fileId, $path)
    {
        try {
            if(!$this->filesDir) throw new Exception("No directory path set. Please check the configurations.");
            $client = $this->getClient();
            $driveService = new Drive($client);
            $file = $driveService->files->get($fileId);
            $fileName = $file->getName();

            $response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array('alt' => 'media', 'supportsAllDrives' => true));
            // $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            $filepath = $path.date('YmdHis').'_'.$fileName;
            $handle = fopen($this->filesDir.$filepath, "w+");
            while (!$response->getBody()->eof()) { 
                fwrite($handle, $response->getBody()->read(1024));
            }
            fclose($handle);
            return $filepath;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Error Message: ".$e;
        }
    }
```

Export file code snippet given below:

```
    public function exportPdf($fileId, $path)
    {
        try {
            if(!$this->filesDir) throw new Exception("No directory path set. Please check the configurations.");
            $client = $this->getClient();
            $driveService = new Drive($client);
            $file = $driveService->files->get($fileId);
            $fileName = $file->getName();
            $filepath = $path.date('YmdHis').'_'.$fileName;
            $response = $driveService->files->export($fileId, 'application/pdf', array('alt' => 'media'));
            $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            if(!empty($content)) {
                file_put_contents($this->filesDir.$filepath, $content);
                return $filepath;
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Empty cotent');
            }
        }  catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Error Message: ".$e;
        }
    
    }
```

I can access those files directly from the google drive (View or Download).

Upload files to Drive is working fine with same scope.

Comment: The user currently authenticated doesnt have access to the file. How are you authorizing this application

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I'm authorizing using oauth. I'm able to download and view files directly from the Drive. With same account I create the App which is used to download the file.

Comment: do a file.list and search for it or try removing 'supportsAllDrives' => true